# Update based on the comma seperated value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below Table with two columns both columns are VARCHAR2(100).

```
PARAM_NAME              PARAM_VALUE
PlanName,DemandMonth    EUMOCP,01-2022
PlanName,DemandMonth    EUMOCP,02-2022
PlanName,DemandMonth    EUMOCP,03-2022
PlanName,DemandMonth    EUMOCP,04-2021
```

How can we write a update on the table so that it only updates the corresponding value.

For example:

Update DemandMonth from 01-2022 to 04-2022.

Provided it only updates the columns based on the first column
For instance,

```
Column A  Column B
1,2        3,4
```

based on 1 we can update 3 as it is before ',' similarly based on 2 we can update 4.

What we want to achieve is the first it identifies where is 'DemandMonth' and then accordingly update the second column. Also if possible can we write it for 4 or 5 comma seperated values?

Comment: First, stop storing param names and param values as comma-separated strings. Store one param and one corresponding value per row. Use multiple rows for the params. Then the update will be easy.

Comment: Don't use delimited strings to store values. Either have a `PlanName` column and a `DemandMonth` column or have 3 columns `ID`, `Param_Name` and `Param_Value` and split every row in your table into 2 rows in the new table so that you can emilinate the comma-delimiters and directly associate name and value.

Comment: Bill we need this together as number of parameters will increase so cannot have separate columns for it

Comment: Need a better solution as using this is not helpful in my scenario.@m

Comment: I appreciate this may not be your design, but one of the core reasons why relational databases were invented was to avoid comma-separated lists.

Answer (score 3):

Don't store values in delimited strings.

Change your table so the values are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE params ( id, param_name, param_value ) AS
SELECT 1, 'PlanName',    'EUMOCP'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'DemandMonth', '01-2022' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'PlanName',    'EUMOCP'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'DemandMonth', '02-2022' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'PlanName',    'EUMOCP'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DemandMonth', '03-2022' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'PlanName',    'EUMOCP'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'DemandMonth', '04-2021' FROM DUAL;
```

Then all you need to do to update the value is:

```sql
UPDATE params
SET   param_value = '04-2022'
WHERE param_name  = 'DemandMonth'
AND   param_value = '01-2022';
```

There is no worrying about where in the delimited string the value is and it is all simple.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this and should refactor your table to not use delimited strings... however, you can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO params dst
USING (
  WITH items ( rid, param_names, param_values, name, value, lvl, max_lvl ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           param_name,
           param_value,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( param_name, '[^,]+', 1, 1 ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( param_value, '[^,]+', 1, 1 ),
           1,
           REGEXP_COUNT( param_value, '[^,]+' )
    FROM   params
  UNION ALL
    SELECT rid,
           param_names,
           param_values,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( param_names, '[^,]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( param_values, '[^,]+', 1, lvl + 1 ),
           lvl + 1,
           max_lvl
    FROM   items
    WHERE  lvl < max_lvl
  )
  SELECT rid,
         LISTAGG(
           CASE
           WHEN name = 'DemandMonth' AND value = '01-2022'
           THEN '04-2022'
           ELSE value
           END,
           ','
         ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY lvl ) AS param_value
  FROM   items
  GROUP BY rid
  HAVING COUNT( 
           CASE
           WHEN name = 'DemandMonth' AND value = '01-2022'
           THEN 1
           END
         ) > 0
) src 
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.rid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET param_value = src.param_value;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE params ( param_name, param_value ) AS
SELECT 'PlanName,DemandMonth',    'EUMOCP,01-2022'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PlanName,DemandMonth',    'EUMOCP,02-2022'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PlanName,DemandMonth',    'EUMOCP,03-2022'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'PlanName,DemandMonth',    'EUMOCP,04-2021'  FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM params;
```

Outputs:

> | PARAM_NAME | PARAM_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | PlanName,DemandMonth | EUMOCP,04-2022 |
> | PlanName,DemandMonth | EUMOCP,02-2022 |
> | PlanName,DemandMonth | EUMOCP,03-2022 |
> | PlanName,DemandMonth | EUMOCP,04-2021 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=60d990c676a7ac8b7af246d9ff006122)*